Integral curves of the differential equation

The photo shows the differential equation $y'=x/y^2$. I need to draw the integral curves of this differential equation. I did it with the help of isoclinical lines. However, the equation is not defined at the point y=0. Will the integral curve pass through the point (0, 0)? Explain the answer too please

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please [don’t use
images](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34121/why-image-cannot-be-used-for-explaining-my-maths-problem) instead of typing your formulas,  and take the time to solve your ODE more carefully.

A solution (kind of) of this equation that passes through $(0,0)$ is
$$
y(x)=\cases{\left(\tfrac 32\right)^{1/3}x^{2/3}\,,&$x\ge 0\,,$\\
-\left(\tfrac 32\right)^{1/3}(-x)^{2/3}\,,&$x< 0\,.$}
$$
Its derivative at $x=0$ is however infinite. If we pass to the ODE for the
inverse function, namely,
$$
x'=\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{y^2}x
$$
we get a solution
$$
x(y)=\operatorname{sgn}(y)\sqrt{\frac{2|y|^3}3}
$$
which is differentiable everywhere and passes through $(0,0)\,.$
